# More thoughts on the election UI

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, election

- <s>There is no lower bound on the self nomination text length. This is puzzling; I'd expect 100 characters *minimum*, certainly not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4729552/revisions):</s>

  > //can moderate

  or [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4729558/revisions):

  > 

  This makes especially sense because there is no voting going on during the first seven days: there is *no* advantage on getting your name in as soon as possible. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- The "Save edits" button really should read "Enter the StackExchange™ PeopleEmpowering Moderator-O-Matic™" or something high and official sounding.
- The "A Theory of Moderation" mention in the self nomination help box should be [linkified](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
- <s>SU's and SF's nomination reputation requirement is 2,000; SO's is 300. Is this by design or an oversight from Maths' elections?</s> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: It looks like the 300 was a typo. The page now states **3000**

Comment: @ChrisF Duly noted.

Comment: there is now a lower bound of 150 chars on a nomination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all completed, except the save edits which I am not entirely sure I agree with yet.